# Resolve module custom main file name

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to define custom main file name?

```
const awesomeModule = require('src/awesomeModule'); // correct
// or
const someModule = require('src/someModule'); // fail
```

There is a structure

```
/src
    /awesomeModule
        - index.js
    /someModule
        - mainFile.js
```

I want an array of possible names. Like a webpack config https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

You can require the main file directly `require('src/someModule/mainFile')`.

Comment: I want an array of possible names. Like a webpack config https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfiles
because i don't know what name i need. it depends on environment variables

Comment: I never used them :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically.

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) you can specify a path to an entry file by adding a `"main"` property in the package.json file.

So, if you really want to do this, you would have to create a new `package.json` inside of the `someModule` folder with these properties:

```
// src/someModule/package.json
{ 
  "name" : "someModule",
  "main" : "./mainFile.js" 
}
```

With that, `require('src/someModule')` will resolve to your `mainFile.js`.

However, in my opinion, I think the confusion caused by having multiple `package.json` files is **not** worth the few extra characters when requiring a module.

Comment: Is a module the same as a package?

Comment: there is no package.json. this is simple node application